# serverless-aws-documentation Unresolved resource dependencies in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, documentation, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am making documentation for my services. I have done few and I got stuck with this one.
It is very weird since this was working fine for the previous ones and also is according to the 
[Serverless AWS Documentation](https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-aws-documentation/)

I have these models in my **serverless.yml**:

```
- name: "Player"
  description: "Golf Player"
  contentType: "application/json"
  schema:
    type: object
    properties:
      FirstName:
        type: string
        description: "Player First Name"
      LastName:
        type: string
        description: "Player Last Name"
- name: "Booking"
  contentType: "application/json"
  schema:
    type: object
    properties:
      _id:
        type: string
        description: "Booking ObjectId"
      slotId:
        type: string
        description: "timeslot ID"
      startTime:
        type: string
        description: "Booking Start Time"
      endTime:
        type: string
        description: "Booking End Time"
      accountId:
        type: string
        description: "Booker Account ID"
      Players:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: "{{model: Player}}"
- name: "ErrorResponse"
  contentType: "application/json"
  schema:
    type: object
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
    statusCode:
        type: number
```

---

### And on of my functions that I am getting error:

```
functions:


getBooking:
    timeout: 300
    handler: handlers/booking/getBooking.handler
    events:
    - http:
        path: /booking/{id}
        method: get
        cors: true
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              id: true
        documentation:
          summary: "GetBooking"
          description: "Gets Booking by bookingNumber"
          tags:
          - "Bookings"
          pathParams:
          - name: "id"
            description: "bookingNumber"
            required: true
          methodResponses:
          - statusCode: "200"
            responseBody:
              description: "Response with Booking object"
              responseHeaders:
              - name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
              - name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
              responseModels:
                "application/json": "Booking"
          - statusCode: "400"
            responseModels:
              "application/json": "ErrorResponse"
          - statusCode: "500"
            responseModels:
              "application/json": "ErrorResponse"
```

I have tried to change models, without quoutes etc but I am still getting this error on deploy:

- **Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ErrorResponseModel] in the Resources block of the template**

If anyone can help, that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do to have a successful result:

1. Remove the quotes from `requestModels` and `responseModels` values.

   ```
   ...
   responseModels:
     "application/json": Booking
   - statusCode: "400"
     responseModels:
       "application/json": ErrorResponse
   - statusCode: "500"
     responseModels:
       "application/json": ErrorResponse
   ```
2. Indent the success (200) response keys (`statusCode`, `responseBody`, `responseHeaders` and `responseModels`) to be on the same line:

   ```
   ...
   - statusCode: "200"
     responseBody:
       description: "Response with Booking object"
     responseHeaders:
       - name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
       - name: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
     responseModels:
       "application/json": Booking
   ...
   ```